# Is order in memory guaranteed for class private members in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, class-members

```
class my_class_t {

private:
    uint64_t field1;
    uint64_t field2;
};
```

Is order of `field1` and `field2` guaranteed in memory by C++ Standard?

UPD. Answers said that `field2` it is, but `&field2` may be not equal to `&field1 + 1`. How to ensure that `field2` will be immediately after `field1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are guaranteed to have increasing addresses with respect to each other ([[class.mem]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.mem#13)):

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class **with the same access
>   control** (Clause [class.access]) are allocated so that later members
>   have higher addresses within a class object.

Note the text I marked in bold. While it's guaranteed `field2` is after `field1` when they are both private, it need not be the case if they had different access control. And of course, intermediate padding is always an option.

But if you want to force the absence of padding, and they are of the same type, an array would do it:

```
uint64_t field[2];
```

It also makes `&field[0] + 1` well defined, since those objects are now obviously members of the same array.

Comment: Thanks! Please look at upd of the question :)

Comment: @Incomputable - Maybe. That's with as much certainty as I'm willing to say. The whole thing is *very* implementation defined.

Comment: @vladon - Since they are of the same type, you can ensure lack of padding by putting them in an array `uint64_t field[2];` - But that is just not pretty

Comment: @Incomputable - You got me thinking about it still :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Actually using an array is extremely pretty indeed.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Oh, just now? I upset the bots and upvoted yours a while ago ;)

Comment: Funnily enough, we disagree on " it need not be the case if they had different access control". In this particular case especially, field2 cannot be before field1 since the address of field1, as the first member, must be the same as the address of the struct.

Comment: @Bathsheba - The dry letter of the law only requires it when they have the same access control. Since the OP asked for the language lawyers perspective, that is it. I also don't recall if there may or may not be padding when the access of the members is not the same as the default access of the class type. But that could just be my brain playing tricks

Comment: @StoryTeller *Since they are of the same type, you can ensure lack of padding by putting them in an array* Does it really ensure a lack of padding, or just that elements can be accessed by pointer arithmetic?  For example, a hypothetical type that's four bytes but that requires 8-byte alignment - there would still be "padding" between the actual 4-byte array elements.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Padding may be added *inside* the object to ensure array elements are laid out continuously. But there is no padding between array elements. The last byte of one object has to be right before the first of another. Even if they are both padding bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the order is guaranteed.

The address of `field1` must be the same as the address of an instance of `my_class_t`. `field2` has a "higher" address than `field1` insofar that positive pointer arithmetic on an `unsigned char*` pointer obtained by a `reinterpret_cast` on the address of `field1` will eventually reach the memory occupied by `field2`.

But note that the behaviour on attempting to "reach" `field2` by pointer arithmetic on a pointer to `field1` is *undefined*.

As for ensuring there is no padding between the members, you can't do that in portable C++. But you could use an array type:

```
class my_class_t {
private:
    uint64_t fields[2];
};
```

which *would* guarantee that. And then you *can* reach the members using pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The order of objects in memory will be same as the order of declaration when access qualifier does not intervene.